# Number Sum in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum, getparameter

I can not do aggregation with JavaScript.

For example:

> https://helloWorld.com/page?id=5

This is working: (Decrease)

```
var mevcutID = getParameterByName('id');
var newPageID = currentID - 1;
window.location.replace("https://helloWorld.com/page?id=" + newPageID);

## return: https://helloWorld.com/page?id=4
```

This is **NOT** working: (Addition)

```
var mevcutID = getParameterByName('id');
var newPageID = currentID + 1;
window.location.replace("https://helloWorld.com/page?id=" + newPageID);

## return: https://helloWorld.com/page?id=51
```

What is the reason of this?

Comment: The `+` operator is also used for string concatenation, and it "prefers" that when one operand is a string. You can write `+currentID` to force that to be a number.

Comment: Because `currentID` is a string. Convert it `Number(currentID)+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to coerce currentID to an number. Right now it's a string and you're appending 1 as a string.

```
var newPageID = +currentID + 1;
```